# Paytm Linked Contacts not able to make phone call

Tags: 7.0-nougat

After regular auto update of apps Some of my contacts shows only the option of Send money through Paytm The solution of Removing Sync is also not working and the contacts are still linked to paytm. I tried to change the app permission settings even then it is still there. Pls help